# Django query filtering

Tags: django, search, date, time

I am creating a popular page for my app and for the most part this is just to gain an understanding.

The idea is to divide the number of views by the days old, now i don't know if this will be successful or even working but like I said its go get an idea of how queries work...

For my view I have:

```
def popular(request):
    popular_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:50]
    return render_to_response(
        'posts/popular.html', 
        {'popular_posts': popular_posts}, 
    )
```

Obviously that just gets all the objects ordered by id. Is there a way to achieve something similar to what I'm looking for without going into loads of complex code?

My fields are named: views and created. Below is an idea of what I'm thinking of.

```
(now - created) / views
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should try accept any previous correct answers to your questions - it will encourage others to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be using [query expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions). However I don't think it's possible to divide datetime objects by numbers using these. I'll try an see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Of course it's always just sort the queryset in python, using the "sorted()" function and providing your own comparison function.